# Remove and Reinitialize jQuery object (Feedback widget)

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using jquery.feedback_me.js, a nice little jQuery Feedback form that remains on the side of the window throughout the browser's experience.

Here is what I want to do. My project is using Zurb's Foundation responsive framework, and I want to remove this feedback tab based on view port size. I was going to manage this by hand, but having a hard time to removing the feedback tab based on event.. and likewise, when the view port is made wider, I want to reinitialize it.

Here is the code to launch the feedback widget:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        fm_options = {
            jQueryUI : true,
            name_placeholder:"Name please",
            trigger_label : "Feedback",
            message_required : true,
            show_asterisk_for_required : true,
            feedback_url : "send_feedback"
        };
        fm.init(fm_options);
    });
```

Thanks!
hanji

Comment: Rather than uninitializing and re-initializing it, why not just give it a class then use media queries to either hide or show said tab? or use window resize event to add/remove the class? uninitializing and reinitializing is far more work than simply showing and hiding it.

Comment: DUH!!! That works perfectly. Talk about making the problem more difficult than it is. Thanks Kevin. Want to add this an answer.. and I'll accept it.